# Python Requests (Web Scraping)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

So I'm trying to make a scraping bot using Python with requests library.
The problem I'm having, is the data I get is delayed (most likely due by cache hits).

I also noticed that each 30~60 seconds, the cache "disappears" and goes back to:

```
cf-cache-status: EXPIRED
cf-ray: <some_hash>
date: Mon, 04 Oct 2021 01:56:03 GMT
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
request-id: <some_id>
server: cloudflare
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-request-id: <some_hash>
```

and then for the same next 30~60 seconds I get only hits and that cache the same request.

```
cf-cache-status: HIT
age: 1 (and counting up)
```

Things I've tried: using requests with proxy,
using selenium webdriver chrome with proxy,
putting time.sleep() between each request.get() - which works but, make my bot not efficient caused by massive delays.

I've also ran into the same issue with CloudFront web scraping.

Would appriciate some help ^^

Comment: Your problem is unclear - are you saying you want fresh results for each request, instead of getting a cache hit?

Comment: @Grismar Yes sir. Sorry for missunderstanding.

Comment: Then your problem is with the server, not with your client. The server decides what to cache and for how long - the mechanism you run into is created for exactly the reason you're getting cached results: so that the server doesn't have to compute the same result over and over.

Comment: @Grismar Yes, I'm aware. So I was wondering if there's any kind of way to bypass it? or any other ideas / scrapers? It must be possible since I've seen other people get the data much faster.

Comment: Mozilla cache control directives may help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control. No guarantees!

Comment: @tdelaney, thanks for trying, but wasn't working.